# How to 3D plot inside subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble plotting a 3D plot inside one of the subplots. I did get the plot but there's an extra layer of labelling that I want to remove.

This is my code and plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(30, 30))

#Trajectory
tau=np.linspace(0,1,n)
ax[0,0].plot(tau,x)
ax[0,0].set_title('1D trajectory')
ax[0,0].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
ax[0,0].set_ylabel('x')

ax[0,1].plot(x,y)
ax[0,1].set_title('2D trajectory')
ax[0,1].set_xlabel('x')
ax[0,1].set_ylabel('y')

ax[0,2] = fig.add_subplot(333, projection='3d')
ax[0,2].plot(x, y, z)

ax[0,2].set_title('3D trajectory')
ax[0,2].set_xlabel('x')
ax[0,2].set_ylabel('y')
ax[0,2].set_zlabel('z')

#MSD-Simulation
ax[1,0].plot(tm,dr1,marker='o',linestyle='none',mec='brown',mfc='none',markevery=1)
ax[1,0].set_title('1D MSD')
ax[1,0].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
ax[1,0].set_ylabel("MSD(\u03C4) [$\u03BCm^2$]")

ax[1,1].plot(tm,dr2,marker='o',linestyle='none',mec='grey',mfc='none',markevery=1)
ax[1,1].set_title('2D MSD')
#ax[1,1].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
#ax[1,1].set_ylabel("MSD(\u03C4) [$\u03BCm^2$]")

ax[1,2].plot(tm,dr3,marker='o',linestyle='none',mec='black',mfc='none',markevery=1)
ax[1,2].set_title('3D MSD')
#ax[1,2].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
#ax[1,2].set_ylabel("MSD(\u03C4) [$\u03BCm^2$]")

#MSD-THEORITICALL
ax[2,0].plot(tm,M1,'brown')
ax[2,0].set_title('1D MSD')
ax[2,0].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
ax[2,0].set_ylabel("MSD(\u03C4) [$\u03BCm^2$]")

ax[2,1].plot(tm,M2,'grey')
ax[2,1].set_title('2D MSD')
#ax[2,1].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
#ax[2,1].set_ylabel("MSD(\u03C4) [$\u03BCm^2$]")

ax[2,2].plot(tm,M3,'black')
ax[2,2].set_title('3D MSD')
#ax[2,2].set_xlabel('\u03C4')
#ax[2,2].set_ylabel("MSD(\u03C4) [$\u03BCm^2$]")

plt.tight_layout()
```

I want to remove the extra layer of labelling @plot(333):

[image: i want to remove the extra layer of labbeling]

Comment: Which labelling do you consider extra?

Comment: remove the previous ax before adding the 3D one with `ax[0,2].remove()`

Comment: @cphlewis the outer 2D labels of plot(222)

Comment: Liris' solution looks right to me -- have you tried it?